# How to persistently modify Windows 11 bootable USB/ISO to bypass requirements instead of opening regedit each time?

Tags: windows, usb, windows-registry, windows-11, iso-image

I was thinking how does the new option in Rufus (the bootable media creation tool) to bypass windows 11 requirements work, as earlier, I had to open regedit each time and insert registry values for each setup instance. But after the option came in rufus, I inspected the regedit and the same values were now persistent on each install. I wanted to know how I can achieve the same, if I also know how to mount the .wim image using DISM (if that is of any use).I want to insert these registry values into the USB/ISO permanently. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sysprep is one way but far easier to use the method Rufus uses, which is open source, so you should be able to determine what modifications it does to the windows image

Comment: What does it (Rufus) exactly do?

Comment: There are only a couple ways to modify a Windows image. How Rufus modifies the image is documented in it's source code. [One way is to XML file that runs commands, that's how Rufus, enables S Mode in the current beta.](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/blob/master/src/wue.c).  In fact CreateUnattendXml is exactly how Rufus does it.  My suggestion is let Rufus create the installation media, copy the create XML file, then modify the windows image yourself if you want.  How you create the unattended XML file, without any prior research (on your part), is way to complicate to explain in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rufus does it two ways:

1. Where possible, it offline edits the registry hive of the `sources\boot.wim` image (the Windows pre-installation environment) to insert the `LabConfig` registry keys that enable the bypass.
2. If that is not possible (e.g. when using the Windows Store version of Rufus, since Microsoft restricts what Windows Store versions can do, and mounting a WIM image is one of these things), Rufus creates an [answer file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/wsim/answer-files-overview) to insert the registry keys at boottime.

Note that the reason we don't just use method #2 all the time is because it results in an unsightly command prompt appearing briefly when the registry keys are applied, and we want the Rufus installation experience to be as close as possible to the regular Windows installation experience, even when the TPM/Secure Boot bypasses are applied.

Note that, since Rufus is 100% Open Source, you can find much of what Rufus does when it applies the various Windows User Experience options in https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/blob/master/src/wue.c.